# exit for loop in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script i am working on and everything works good so far except it doesn't exit the loop when it outputs the info I need

```
uidAssoc(){
        arg1=$1
        arg2=$2
        for i in $(cat ~/jlog/"$2"); do grep "$1" ~/jlog/"$2" | awk '/\([a-zA-Z0-9.]+/ {print $7}'; done | awk -F'[(/]' '{print $2;exit}'
        echo "Study Instance UID has been found!!"
        break
```

I know it doesn't get past this loop because I `echo "Study Instance UID has been found!!"` and it doesn't produce that echo statement as output. Can someone suggest what else I can do?

Comment: You have `break` outside `for` loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
uidAssoc(){
        arg1=$1
        arg2=$2
        for i in $(cat ~/jlog/"$2")
          do
          # ...
          echo "Study Instance UID has been found!!"
          break
        done
}
```